# MySQL Select Top Row Grouping By Another Row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a sales table and I want to get each members most frequently shopped store in the last 3 months. The following query will get the every member with every store, but I want just one store per member.

```
SELECT member_id, store_id, COUNT(DISTINCT docket) as docket_count, SUM(dollar_amount) as dollars
FROM sales
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, sale_date, CURDATE()) < 3
GROUP BY member_id, store_id
ORDER BY member_id, docket_count DESC, dollars DESC
```

Or to get the top store for a single member

```
SELECT store_id, COUNT(DISTINCT docket) as docket_count, SUM(dollar_amount) as dollars
FROM sales
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, sale_date, CURDATE()) < 3
AND member_id = 1
GROUP BY store_id
ORDER BY docket_count DESC, dollars DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  In MySQL, this can be easiest using the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
SELECT member_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(store_id ORDER BY docket_count DESC  dollars DESC), ',', 1) as Most_Common_Store
FROM (SELECT member_id, store_id, COUNT(DISTINCT docket) as docket_count, 
             SUM(dollar_amount) as dollars
      FROM sales
      WHERE sale_date >= CURDATE() - interval 3 month
      GROUP BY member_id, store_id
     ) ms
GROUP BY member_id;
```